# Difference in R performance between two different machines running the same script

Tags: r

I am running same code on unix (its a cluster) and on windows (intel core duo ,2Gb RAM). I can see there is significant difference in running time. I can see in unix, its using only one core, but on windows, it may be using two cores (i m not sure). My concern is the following:

```
Windows:
   user  system elapsed
207.12 8.82  472.04
Unix
 user  system elapsed
327.765 2.493 330.819
```

what I dont understand, why there is too much difference in cpu processing time and elapsed time for windows. I broke the code into segments and this happens only on reading and writing part (I/O), rest of calculations are very fast comparative to unix and doesnt have any difference in 'user' and 'elapsed' time

```
user  system elapsed
48.765 0.00 52.69
```

I am not doing any thing special, but I m reading very big file some 300mb

```
indata <- read.csv(mutFile, sep="\t", header = TRUE)
```

How can I avoid this difference to improve overall performance?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example which people can use to recreate your situation. Right now we are left guessing.

Comment: Where are the files your program reads from/to located in both cases? Reading from a hard drive versus a network drive could make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get high performance in reading a dataset, I would recommend buying a solid state drive (SSD). However, your other hardware (mainly your SATA controller) might be a bottle neck. Also, SSD's are not cheap in terms of Gb/unit money. In general, the difference in performance can be explained by the difference in hardware ('normal' harddrive vs laptop harddrive). The solution is to spend money on a faster machine. Alternatively, like @JoshuaUlrich said, spend some time optimizing reading of text files to get good performance boosts with your current hardware.

Comment: Can you explain me why there is too much difference in "cpu time" and 'total elapsed' time? I probably dont understand that part. As, I mentioned, all the calculation part doesnt have any differen in 'cpu time' and 'elapsed time' and they are quick too

Comment: The cpu's on your linux computer and windows computer are probably comparable, making cpu-bound calculations roughly equal in performance on both machines. The difference arises in reading the dataset probably because of a difference in disk reading speed, where the linux computer has a faster harddrive. Is the windows machine by any chance a laptop?

Comment: Laptops generally have slower harddrives (5400 rpm) in constrast to desktop pc's (7200 rpm's) which leads to the difference in disk reading speed you see.

Answer (score 2):

300 MB is far from "very big".  You can increase the speed of `read.csv` by following the advice in `?read.csv`, specifically the section on "Memory Usage".  That should make run-times on both systems much shorter.

As for the difference between the systems, I suspect the Unix box has a faster HDD and/or faster RAM.

Comment: I first hadn't read the question correctly, but there are two different computers involved...

Comment: The windows pc is actually a laptop, probably with a slow 5400 rpm disk, where the Linux box probably has a faster 7200 rpm disk.

Comment: Or the Windows PC is a desktop with a 7200 RPM disk and the Unix box is a server with a RAID array and/or 10k RPM disks.

Comment: The OP confirmed in a comment to my answer that the windows pc was a laptop. But the general idea also applies to your example.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: yes, I noticed you guessed correctly in the comments.  I guessed correctly (but more generally) in my answer.  I was simply pointing out that your specific guess about one being a desktop and one being a laptop didn't have to be the case.  In fact, they could both be desktops with 7200 RPM drives and one could have a RAID array.

Comment: I had bad experiences with read.csv function before too. Just as the help suggests, scan function should be used for large to huge files. Or you can use other packages, like data.table.